# Not Working: Track YouTube video views and comments

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Google's YouTube Stat tracking AppScript seems to have stopped working in the new year. When I try to run the script, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
> extractVideoIdFromUrl @ Code.gs:110
> (anonymous)   @ Code.gs:58
> markVideos    @ Code.gs:40

Any ideas how I can fix this? Is it possible to fix on my end?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/youtube-tracker

I tried inspecting the code for any references to the date that might cause it to stop working. Didn't find any.

Comment: indexOf() is an array method so check the array because evidently it is undefined

Comment: Which function were you running?

Comment: To be honest I'm not so familiar with the code - the spreadsheet was created by the  Google Dev team and just stopped working. Usually it runs automatically every day, and manually if you hit the "run" button.

Comment: Please post the code you have

Comment: Code is too long to post but here is the github:

https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples/blob/main/solutions/automations/youtube-tracker/Code.js

Comment: - [Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, or anyone who writes code because they love it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified some functions in the code and they are now working properly. Please check the sheet, I am giving you the editor access.

sheet link- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FE75UZ2i2D0_3SQNJZ8WSvHfM0YUrrXl_wcmdKm7TQ8

Script Link- https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/1zdTpvslHwEde7IM7ktG_ZyaAOQwVApkqaQnwnttRKix1pddhT0eLda_L

if you face any issues feel free to ask.

Best regards,
Bikram.